# Not able to enable Hyper-V on Windows 10- Changes revert after rebooting

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v

I have been trying to enable Hyper-V on my laptop: Dell Latitude E6440 with Windows 10 Pro. I am following [this link to do the same](http://techgenix.com/installing-configuring-and-using-hyper-v-windows-10/) but after rebooting my system on selecting Hyper-V options from 'Turn Windows features on or off', the changes are being reverted.

As described in the link, I have made sure that my hardware supports virtualization:
[image]

I also tried after disabling my network adapter but even that didn't work for me.

Kindly help me out with this.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

At last, found the cause! Seems like an update KB4074588 didn't get installed and was preventing container and Hyper-V Features to be installed as well.

Tried running the following command in CMD:

```
SC config trustedinstaller start=auto
```

and then got the updates installed properly. My system rebooted too.

Before doing the above, it should be made sure that the following have been verified:

- You have Virtualization supported Windows 10 version (PRO, etc)
- Your PC hardware supports virtualization. If not sure run systeminfo in admin CMD and you should see at the bottom all virtualizations marked as Yes
  Enabled Virtualization (Hyper-V, etc) in your BIOS
- If you are connected to Active Domain (company computer/network) there are no policies preventing virtualization.